# Deploying Bot service v4

Tags: c#, botframework

Seems like it's suppose to be a simple trivial process given the very few resources on this topic but I can't seem to understand it. The official documentation has one page that uses default deployment templates:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

But I can't get it to work or understand what it's doing.

I tried creating my own app service, and bot channel registration (with app id/secret). I've made a build pipeline that puts the code into the app service but now I'm stuck. How exactly is the app service supposed to connect to the bot registration? The appsettings file has "MicrosoftAppId" and "MicrosoftAppPassword" but it doesn't seem to be used anywhere in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it working following this guide:
http://blog.aterentiev.com/2019/07/step-by-step-configure-bot-to-work-in.html

Just a note, if you create an app registration and choose "Accounts in this organizational directory only" then the web chat test will not respond